# What is the difference between weights and variables in a Keras Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I notice that `tf.keras.Model`s have two similar sets of attributes:

`weights`, `variables`
`trainable_weights`, `trainable_variables`
`non_trainable_weights`, `non_trainable_variables`

There are also methods:

`add_weight`, `add_variable`

In the models I've looked at, the values of the pairs of attributes are the same, and are what you'd expect (the appropriate collections of `tf.Variable`s).

So my question is: what is the difference between the two? What is the difference conceptually, and when should I use one or the other?

This is TensorFlow 2.3.1.

Answer (score 5):

If we look at [the code of `tf.keras.layers.Layer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L2247-L2255), we see that `trainable_variables` and `non_trainable_variables` are simple getter around `trainable_weights` and `non_trainable_weights`

```
@property
@doc_controls.do_not_generate_docs
def trainable_variables(self):
  return self.trainable_weights

@property
@doc_controls.do_not_generate_docs
def non_trainable_variables(self):
  return self.non_trainable_weights
```

I believe that this is done for consistency. In the tensorflow code base, you can find that a lot of code non related to the high API keras that also have those two properties (`trainable_variables` and `non_trainable_variables`).

However, looking at the code from the keras repository, it is clear that keras was using `trainable_weights` and `non_trainable_weights` to reference the same concept. See the [Layer class in keras 2.2](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.0/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L45-L55)

Answer (score 3):

`add_variable` and the related bits appear to be a legacy from Tensorflow 1. As of today's master `add_variable` is an alias for `add_weight` and issues a deprecation warning if called.

[Source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/46a9034c6806455116dd8decdb5c0faea9a04dc2/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L2273)